# How do I get data out of a JSON object in MVC

Tags: javascript, json, model-view-controller, asp.net-mvc-5

I have the following JSON object where all data is stored.

```
[{"id":1,"CoinValue":"0.01","Count":82,"CoinWeight":76},
{"id":2,"CoinValue":"0.02","Count":86,"CoinWeight":18},
{"id":3,"CoinValue":"0.05","Count":29,"CoinWeight":42},
{"id":4,"CoinValue":"0.1","Count":35,"CoinWeight":90},
{"id":5,"CoinValue":"0.2","Count":23,"CoinWeight":3},
{"id":30,"CoinValue":"0.5","Count":41,"CoinWeight":36}]
```

I want to get the CoinValue and Count of each record for displaying in google charts. Currently, I have the view calling a method called Data in the Coin controller to receive the data but I cannot get this working.

CoinController:

```
    public ActionResult Data()
    {
        //Read Json object
        var fileContents = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(@"H:\EasyAsPiMVC\EasyAsPiMVC\App_Data\MOCK_DATA.json");

        //not sure how to properly pass this data to the view 

        return Json(fileContents);
    }
```

Javascript in view for handling and displaying the data

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: "Json",
        contentType: "application/json",
        url: '@Url.Action("Data", "Coin")',
        success: function (result) {
            google.charts.load('current', {
                'packages': ['corechart']
            });
            google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(function () {
                drawChart(result);
            });
        }
    });

    function drawChart(result) {
        var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
        data.addColumn("string", "CoinValue"); //might have to be changed
        data.addColumn("number", "Count");
        var dataArray = [];
        $.each(result, function (i, obj) {
            dataArray.push([obj.CoinValue, obj.Count]);
        });
        data.addRows(dataArray);

        var piechart_options = {
            title: 'Coin Tracker Piechart',
            width: 400,
            height: 300
        };

        var piechart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('piechart_div'));
        piechart.draw(data, piechart_options);

        var barchart_options = {
            title: 'Coin Tracker barchart',
            width: 400,
            height: 300,
            legend: 'none'
        };

        var barchart = new google.visualization.BarChart(document.getElementById('barchart_div'));
        barchart.draw(data, barchart_options);
    }
});
</script>
```

I am a programming noob and have not been able to figure this out for over a day now. I have done a significant amount of research but I just can't seem to get this working.

Comment: using angular would help you in the long run, not an answer but more of a recommendation.

Comment: what is not working for you? do you get any errors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ReadAllText` method gives you a `string` , which is the content of the file. You need to deserialize it to a list of `Coin` objects. Your client side code expects an array of objects, each with a `CoinValue` and `Count` property. So you need to return that json array.

Here is how you will do it with JSON.NET

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Data()
{
    var path = "Path to your JSON file goes here";
    var fileContents = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(path);
    var list = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Coin>>(fileContents);
    return Json(list);
}
```

Comment: Than you, i was trying something very similar to this earlier but was using a different model class that just held a list of coin objects which didn't work. Thanks so much!